# How to mock NextJS next/future/image in Storybook

Tags: next.js, storybook, nextjs-image, nextjs-storybook

How can I mock [next/future/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image) component from NextJS in Storybook?

Answer (score 0):

Mock with support of [fill](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image#fill) property from `v12.2.4`

```js
// .storybook/preview.js

import * as NextFutureImage from "next/future/image";

Object.defineProperty(NextFutureImage, "default", {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => {
    const { fill, style, ...restProps } = props;

    return (
      <img
        {...restProps}
        style={
          fill
            ? {
                position: "absolute",
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                inset: 0,
                ...style
              }
            : style
        }
      />
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: If the Next.js image includes both `fill` and `style`, this will overwrite the original `style` completely. I suggest resolving the style attribute by merging the `fill` styles with the image's styles (if provided).